# Patching module level function(generator) in Python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, generator

I have a module level method (which is a generator). I want to supply custom implementation of that method (not just return value while testing another class. I also need to change some parameters(instance variables)  of the class at test time.

**module x:**

```
def zone_file_iterator():
    pass
```

**module y:**

```
from x import zone_file_iterator()

class PleaseTestMe(CachedSingleTon):
      def __init__():
        self.a

      @classmethod
      def load_data(cls):
        """
        do some thing with large data file.
        """
        zone_file_iterator()
```

To test the above class , I believe using the Mock Framework in Python Unittest, can we do some thing like this ? Please correct me if this is wrong.

```
   @patch('y.PleaseTestMe.a', customvalue)
   @patch('x.zone_file_iterator', x.custome_small_data_iterator)
   def test_skip_grams():
      """
      Instantiate the class and write Assert Logic here.
      """
      pass
```

Comment: I don't know unittest very well, but I'd guess you don't want the extra parentheses in your `patch` call. Try `@patch('x.zone_file_iterator', x.comtome_small_data_iterator)`

Comment: So, now that you've changed the call, what's your remaining question? Does that code work? Why not try it and find out?